# reference variable in java

Tags: java, reference, default

what is the default value of a reference variable in java (like it is 0 for primitive int etc)
moreover when( or how) is a reference variable assigned NO VALUE and when is it assigned THE VALUE "NULL"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This depends on where that variable is declared:

- If it is a member variable (i.e. a field) then its default value is `null`.
- If it is a local variable, then it has no default value, and you must assign it before its first use (the compiler throws an error if you try using a variable unassigned).

Answer (score 1):

Default value of a reference variable is `null` by default if it is marked as class variable else it needs explicit initialization.

Answer (score 0):

Null is the default. When you assign an object to the reference variable, then the reference is no longer null and instead points to the object.

Answer (score 0):

> Data Type...........Default Value (for fields)
>
> byte, int , short......................0
>
> float.................................0.0f
>
> double............................   0.0d
>
> char.................................'\u0000'
>
> String (or any object)............... NULL